# How to cite a Google Play app?

Tags: publications, citations, bibtex

In my paper I need to cite an Android application.

There is an official way to cite the site Google Play?

I know the tag `@misc` on BibTeX, but I am looking for a standard style, if exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do so in the APA style:

[APA Style Blog: How to Cite a Mobile App](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2013/03/how-to-cite-a-mobile-app.html)

If you were to translate the citation to another citation style, the pieces of information that you need are the author, name, and version of the application, and the operating system it was written for. You should also include where the app was downloaded from (in this case, play.google.com). Make sure any links are permalinks.

Comment: "Make sure any links are permalinks." - actually, this is arguably somewhat *less* important here than otherwise when citing online resources. While, for instance, Google might at some point in the future decide to restructure the URLs in their playstore, the unique *package ID* will still be a part of the outdated URL and can thus be found again even in a restructured store.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper true, perhaps it's better to say "make sure that any links aren't *known to be temporary*". Anyhoo, if Google were to restructure their URLs, it might be sensible for them to set up redirects for the old links. Unless the link is specific to a particular version or browser session, it'll probably stick around for a while.

Comment: The app is developed in my University. I must cite it, but I was looking for a standard (if exist). Your link is a good answer.